# Disable Button Listener inside a popover content using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I want to submit different input data using the same pre-generated html form template (they just have different variable names as titles). On my page, I have two buttons which have basically the same popover effects. When I clicked `submit` (this is the button inside a `.popover-content`, it appears that I submit both forms even though one of them is hidden.

```
function handlePopover (button) {
  const id = button.attr('id');
  $(document).on('click', '#close', function(){
    botton.popover('hide');
  }
  $(document).on('click', '#submit', function(){
    if(id === 'button1') alert("button1");
    else if(id === 'button2') alert("button2");
  }
}
```

This is how I used this function:

```
const button1 = $("#button1");
const button2 = $("#button2");
handlePopover(button1);
handlePopover(button2);
```

It's probably because I added a listener like this `$(document).on(...)`. But I didn't know how to solve this problem. Can I deactivate the listener when the popover content is hidden? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out. You need to add a listener to the popover button before adding a listener to the submit button.

```
button.on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
  // add a listener to the submit button 
  $(document).on('click', '#submit', function(){
    if(id === 'button1') alert("button1");
    else if(id === 'button2') alert("button2");
  }
}
```